# Перенаправление в руби

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

В `routes.rb` сделал ограничение на вход, если старый браузер и перенаправление всех ссылок на страничку, с инормацией,что нужно обновить браузер. Но, почему-то отказывается работать. Имею такой код в `routes`.

```
  constraints OldBrowser do
    match "*path"  "tech_messages#old_browser", via: :all
  end
```

вызывую метод на объекте Request с тем же именем тут

```
class OldBrowser
  def self.mathces?(request)
    Browser.new(request.user_agent).chrome? && Browser.new(request.user_agent).full_version >= "51"
  end
end
```

И ничего.Поменял условие немного, чтобы страничка появлялась при браузере выше 51 версии.

Comment: "Имею такой код" в начале файла или в конце?

Comment: В начале файла.

Comment: Поставьте бряк отладчика внутри `matches?`, изучите посылаемый запрос, возможно он действительно не подходит.

Comment: Действительно, в этом же файле, при определении desktop или mobile , можно забайбажить, а вот  в oldbrowser - не хочет

Comment: А. Тьфу. `mathces?` != `matches?` :)

Comment: Мда, не заметил даже, спасибо